# "Error converting data type nvarchar to float" with CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to run a query with the following as one of the select statements, and I keep getting the error "Error converting data type nvarchar to float." I've been converting VBA IIf statements to CASES and I can't seem to get the conversions right. fld2 is nvarchar(15) and fld1 is a float data type. I need help pinpointing why this error is being thrown.

```
 CASE WHEN (IsNumeric([fld2]) = 1) THEN Round(Convert(nvarchar,[fld2]) + 
   ' / ' + Convert(nvarchar,[fld1]),(Len(Convert(nvarchar,[theData])) -
  Charindex(Convert(nvarchar, [fld2]),'.'))) ELSE [fld2] END,
```

Comment: I believe CASE evaluates all of its parts so even if `IsNumeric` is false and `ELSE` part is executed - first part still attempts to calculate

Comment: Why are you passing a string in to the `ROUND()` function?

Comment: Using round to give the result of converting international measurements to U.S. measurments

Comment: `ROUND()` expects a numeric type, though, not a string; as does your division operands.

Comment: Yea I could be confused about parts of the system. That code was previously in VBA where it went something like... 'Round(Eval(fld2 & '/' & fld1)) ... maybe I just need to find a function that divides two values in an sql query

Comment: @tripleddev: Looks like that VBA was evaluating an expression representing the division of two numbers in string format, and then rounding them. Division in SQL can be done with a simple `/` operator, but the values on each side need to be numbers.

Comment: @Cory, so essentially I can write 'Round([fld1]/[fld2])' given that the fields are numbers.

Comment: @tripleddev: Exactly, but they have to be numeric *types*, not just strings that represent numbers, so that's where the type conversion comes into play. So if `[fld2]` is `nvarchar(15)`, then you would need: `ROUND(CONVERT(float, [fld2]) / [fld1], 2)`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, your example would produce quite a funny expression for SQL server to evaluate. Let's substitute values for `fld1`, `fld2`, and `theData` as an example to see what you're trying to do:

```
[fld1]    = 42.0
[fld2]    = N'69.56'
[theData] = N'something'
```

<sup>(an `N` before a string makes it an `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`)</sup>

With substitutions, the resulting query would look like this:

```
CASE WHEN (IsNumeric(N'69.56') = 1) THEN 
    Round(Convert(nvarchar,'69.56') + ' / ' + Convert(nvarchar, 42.0),
        (Len(Convert(nvarchar,'something')) - Charindex(Convert(nvarchar, N'69.56'),'.')))  
ELSE 
    N'69.56' 
END
```

Since you don't need to convert an `nvarchar` to `nvarchar` explicitly, your query actually looks more like:

```
CASE WHEN (IsNumeric(N'69.56') = 1) THEN 
    Round(N'69.56 / ' + Convert(nvarchar, 42.0),
        (Len(N'something') - Charindex(N'69.56','.')))  
ELSE 
    N'69.56'
END
```

**So there are a couple of problems:**

1. You're passing a `varchar` value into the `ROUND()` function, which expects a numeric value, not an expression
2. The two paths of the `CASE` statement are returning different types

What I think your query should look like is:

```
CASE WHEN IsNumeric([fld2]) = 1 THEN 
    CONVERT(nvarchar, ROUND(CONVERT(float, [fld2]) / [fld1],
        (LEN([theData]) - CHARINDEX([fld2], '.'))))
ELSE 
    [fld2]
END
```

The above does the math and rounding on numeric results instead of strings, doesn't do any unnecessary conversions, and also returns the same type in both cases.

Comment: I really appreciate this response. I am currently an intern going over some complex systems and I don't always get the guidance I need and so I might not understand what the system is actually doing. On top of that I've only had basic VB for programming so far.

Comment: Of course this code assumes FLD1 will never be 0. I try to account for the divide by zero problem too.